# Django 3.1: Choice of static files directory

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-3.1

I have seen different ways in tutorials where the static files directory keep on changing.

**1.** Some put static files in the project root directory. Example

```
myproject
|__blog
|  |__migrations
|  |__static 
|  |__templates
mysite
|
static
   |__blog
         |__css
         |__js
```

**2.** Some put the static files in the root directory of the app it is serving. Example

```
myproject
├── blog
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
└── mysite
```

Where should static files be located?

Comment: The answer is whichever option suits you. If it is a standalone project I would go for option 1. If it is an app that is made for public use (a package others would use in their projects) one would use option 2. **Note**: At the end all static files are going to be collected in a common directory for production.

Comment: The answer is both. You will have static files related to the project. Those go in the project static directory. The app-specific static files go in the static folder of the app. Remember to namespace static files.

Answer (score 0):

It's whatever you want.
Personally, I prefer to keep my static resources at one place instead of scattered in different applications. Moreover, most staticfiles are needed in multiple apps, so I just put everything one place and serve from there.